# AWS S3 public json filie hosting with restricted access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-hosting

So what I have been trying to do is to host some `.json` files in my `s3` buckets that can be retrieved by simple `GET` requests.

I followed this [aws guideline](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/09/connect-your-git-repository-to-amazon-s3-and-aws-services-using-webhooks-and-new-quick-start/) and managed to host some files that can be publicly accessed. Right now I can simply type something like this in the browser address bar and get my json file:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/[my-bucket-name]/[my-file-name].json
```

or I can also do this in console:

```
curl -X GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/[my-bucket-name]/[my-file-name].json
```

What I want to do now is to add a very basic security to my bucket of files: I want to allow access only if the request contains a certain API key in the header. For now I just want a single API key kind of design where all users just share the same exact api key, and anyone with that key should be able to access any file in the bucket.

Something like this curl command:

```
 curl -X GET --header "X-ApiKey: wow-such-secret" https://s3.amazonaws.com/[my-bucket-name]/[my-file-name].json
```

I am wondering if this is possible just with S3. If I need to use other Amazon services, which services should I look into?

My bucket policy (I basically copy-pasted from the aws tutorial):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[my-bucket-name]/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also I have ~10h of AWS and ~1 month of server development experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use AWS API GATEWAY along with a lambda function to achieve your goal

Use the API Gateway for rest calls that will contain your header in the request, API Gateway already has such implementation in their [Usage Plans with API Keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html), this will allow you to create your own **api key** which will be passed in the request making sure that only request with your header are allowed.

Then you can hook the [lambda function](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/features/) to your API Gateway endpoint. The lambda function can give a signed url to your S3 resource or return the json data from the bucket but that depends on your preference.

You have two solutions and their flows are:

Signed Url solution:

(request with your header) <--> (API GateWay) <--> (lambda) -[generates a signed url]
another request to get the file on the bucket.
(client)+ (signed url) <--> s3Bucket

Without signed URL: 
Lambda function will read/get the file for you.
(request with your header) <--> (API GateWay) <--> (lambda) <--> S3

**PLEASE NOTE** Set the persmissions to authenticated read only on your S3 Bucket.

If you are only storing JSON files data in your bucket I suggest you use [dynamodb](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_ZA&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=dynamodb_hv_b&sc_content=dynamodb_e&sc_detail=dynamodb&sc_category=dynamodb&sc_segment=67727538662&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=ZA&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!67727538662!e!!g!!dynamodb&ef_id=Cj0KCQiAheXiBRD-ARIsAODSpWOK2H9QapzuO3Nm42hn1XPfJwV_cjw-Xx0ha6dcTyBnDKjQ-u0woR4aAnZaEALw_wcB:G:s) as its already optimized for storing JSON data.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like that's a lot of new things to learn but now I know at least where to look.

Comment: just comment here if you get stuck or have more questions